# how to compare each record with the median of the whole set of data in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, median

I have a calculated field for the median, but I want to filter on each record, compare it with the median. The issue is when filtered, the median becomes the record itself. how can I fixed the median?

Thanks.

Comment: Learn about LOD calculations and how they interact with filters. Described in the Tableau documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest Tableau, then you can use LOD calculation as advised by Alex. In your case, simply wrapping it in {} should do the trick: `{MEDIAN([Sales])}` 
This will configure the calculation to ignore the effects of the filter. But if your worksheet is complicated, then more modifications to the formula might be required.

If you are using older versions of Tableau, then there is a more complicated workaround with table calculations and special filters to achieve the same result.